# C# Is there any better way to use Switch-Case / If-Else on generic types

Tags: c#, if-statement, generics, casting, switch-statement

I am currently trying to get some casting on generic types done.
So the base idea is to have a method which accepts a generic Type and does different stuff depending on which type gets passed in.

For simplicity reasons I will just showcase the use of `float`, `bool` and `default`

The setup looks something like this (where `T` is a generic type defined by the class itself):

```
protected T DoStuff(T value)
{
   switch (value) {
      case float floatValue:
         float result = DoFloatStuff(floatValue);
         switch (result) {
            case T output:
               return output;
         }
      case bool boolValue:
         bool result = DoBoolStuff(boolValue);
         switch (result) {
            case T output:
               return output;
         }
      default:
         // return value;
         DoRealGenericStuff(value) // Edited, since I just want to sort out some special cases
   }
}
```

Where `DoFloatStuff` and `DoBoolStuff` are just methods that have 1 parameter and a return type of their types respectively.

If I don't do it like that (I tried some `typeof()` casting before), the compiler always complains that it cannot cast from `T` to `float` and vice versa, even tho I made sure that would be the case with some Case-Switch / If-Else statements.

Does anybody know some better way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
BOTHLine

Edit:
Since a lot of people said kind of the same thing, that I either shouldn't use generics at all in a case like that or my methods would need to be more generic themselves..
My problem here is that I need to use 3rd party methods to handle the special cases I'm checking for (in this case the `float` and `bool` types). For the default case I already handled everything in a generic way. But for some defined types I just can't do that.

So to go a little more in detail why that's the case:
I'm currently working on a Plugin for the "Unity Engine". Unity has built in methods to display types (kind of all primitive types and some Unity-specific types). I have a generic Wrapper class which should be able to contain any types. But then when I want to display the content of that wrapper in the GUI that Unity Editor offers, I have to use the built-in methods to display the primitives (something like `UnityEditor.EditrGUI.FloatField()`). Without those methods I am never able to display anything.
Anything else which can be broken down to those types can then be displayed in a more generic way.

Comment: If `DoFloatStuff` and `DoBoolStuff` are so different that they can't be "genericized" then you have no use of generics. Just give up and have `object DoStuff(object value)`.

Comment: @Dialecticus thats should be the only option if you dont know the object's type. If the compiler can figure out the type at compile time then he should be using method overloading, not generics, and most definitely not `object`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So the base idea is to have a method which accepts a generic Type and does different stuff depending on which type gets passed in.

That is the wrong idea. It's not the way generics should be used. In such a case, you should use method overloading to create the `DoStuff` for each type individually:

```cs
float DoStuff(float value) {/* float implementation here */}
bool DoStuff(bool value) {/* bool implementation here */}
...
```

The point of generic is to enable you to write a code that will run the same on different types - so it should either be used where the type itself is irrelevant to the code (like in any generic collection) or can be executed with an interface or a base class all the acceptable types implement (or inherits). At this point, generics is usually only needed when you want a method to return a specific implementation of an interface (or base class).

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your comment. First I edited my initial post to make myself a little more clear, since I did not explain everything really well. Because of course I wanted to handle most cases in a generic way, there were just some special cases I need to sort out.

But well yeah, your "that's not the idea of generics" really made me think. And I should be able to just use the method `DoStuff` in a generic way and then inherit with my special cases and override that method in the right way, because there I won't have to do any type checking anymore. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let the compiler sort it out for you:

```
protected void DoStuff(float v){}
protected void DoStuff(int v){}
// and so on
//and finally the default:
protected void DoStuff(object v){}

public void Work(T value)
{
    DoStuff(value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the short answer but it's the right way (by many standards). There might be a short answer but, if I were you I wouldn't bother.

This is the smell of a factory pattern. A generic should be, as the name suggests, generic and indifferent to the types if it is you can do something like this.

```
interface IDoStuffer<T>
{
    T DoStuff(T value)
}

class DoStuffFloat : IDoStuff<float>
{
    public float DoStuff(float value)
    {
        //Do your float stuff
    }
}

class DoStuffBool : IDoStuff<bool>
{
    public bool DoStuff(bool value)
    {
        //Do your bool stuff
    }
}
```

Then you can have a factory give you a correct implementation

```
class DoStuffFactory
{
    public IDoStuff<T> GetDoStuff<T>()
    {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(float))
            return new DoStuffFloat();
        //And other types
    }
}
```