# Dynamic parameter list of different out types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, syntax, parameters

I have an object that provides several functions to write and read data from a packet, something like this:

```cs
class Packet
{
    void    Write(int value) {/*...*/}
    //...

    int     ReadInt()     {/*...*/}
    bool    ReadBool()    {/*...*/}
    string  ReadString()  {/*...*/}
    Vector3 ReadVector3() {/*...*/}
}
```

this class stores a `byte[]` that is sent over the network. If I want to access data previously written, I can do it like this

```cs
void MyFunction(Packet packet)
{
    int     myInt     = packet.ReadInt();
    bool    myBool    = packet.ReadBool();
    string  myString  = packet.ReadString();
    Vector3 myVector3 = packet.ReadVector3();
    //... do stuff
}
```

I was wondering if there is some syntactic sugar that would allow me to define a function taking a variable number of parameters of different types, detect which dynamic types they are at runtime, call the appropriate function and then return the parameter, something like this:

```cs
class Packet
{
    //...
    void ReadAll(out params object[] objects);
}

void MyFunction(Packet packet)
{
    packet.ReadAll(out int myInt, out bool myBool, out string myString, out Vector3 myVector3);
    //... do stuff with myInt, myBool, myString, myVector3
}
```

I looked at `params` with an `object[]`, the `out` keyword, generics, and `Convert.ChangeType()` but I couldn't get anything to work so far. I'm not sure this is even possible, and if it is, if the runtime cost of reflection will highly outweigh the benefits of simpler/less code for something used as frequently as network packets.

Thank you all.

Comment: You could do something like: 

public class MyPacket : Packet, IReadContent

------------------

IReadContent can then be an implementation that returns a generic type

Then whatever packetType is relevant for the instance of "MyPacket" will then have a Read method? 

Perhaps dependency inject on the constructor a "reader" that can be of different types instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using generics and `ValueTuples`:

```
public T Read<T>() where T:ITuple
{
    return default(T); // some magic to create and fill one
}
```

and usage:

```
var (i, j) = Read<(int, int)>();
// or
var x = Read<(int i, int j)>();
```

As for reflection - you can cache reflection "results" per type:

```
public T Read<T>() where T : struct, ITuple
{
    return TupleCreator<T>.Create(new ValueReader());
}

static class TupleCreator<T> where T : struct, ITuple
{
    private static Func<ValueReader, T> factory; 
    
    static TupleCreator()
    {
        var fieldTypes = typeof(T).GetFields()
            .Select(fi => fi.FieldType)
            .ToArray();
            
        if(fieldTypes.Length > 7)
        {
            throw new Exception("TODO");
        }

        var createMethod = typeof(ValueTuple).GetMethods()
            .Where(m => m.Name == "Create" && m.GetParameters().Length == fieldTypes.Length)
            .SingleOrDefault() ?? throw new NotSupportedException("ValueTuple.Create method not found.");

        var createGenericMethod = createMethod.MakeGenericMethod(fieldTypes);
        
        var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ValueReader));
        // you will need to figure out how to find your `read` methods
        // but it should be easy - just find a method starting with "Read"
        // And returning desired type
        // I can do as simple as:
        var readMethod = typeof(ValueReader).GetMethod("Read");
        var readCalls = fieldTypes
            .Select(t => readMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t)) // can cache here also but I think not needed to
            .Select(m => Expression.Call(par, m));
        var create = Expression.Call(createGenericMethod, readCalls);
        factory = Expression.Lambda<Func<ValueReader, T>>(create, par).Compile();
    }
    
    public static T Create(ValueReader reader) => factory(reader);
}

class ValueReader
{
    public T Read<T>()
    {
        return default; // to simulate your read
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(Read<(int i, double j)>()); // prints "(0, 0)"
```

**NB**

Also you can just implement the `Read<T>` method with "caching" the reflection as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62032288/2501279).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Reflection is always having a cost of Performance, but it's not always so big, especially when you are not using reflective calls via big size collections or dealing with a very complicated code ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/july/using-net-avoid-common-performance-pitfalls-for-speedier-apps) is a Microsoft official tutorial about when to use the Reflection).

Anyway, back to our business, using a reflection here is what I think might help you:

```cs
class Packet {
    
    ...

    public T Read<T>()
    {
        var currentType = Type.GetType(this.GetType().ToString());

        var methodInfo = currentType?
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance) // Getting all "private" read methods
            .FirstOrDefault(m =>
                m.Name.Contains("Read") && m.ReturnType == typeof(T));


        // here it is assuming that you will have to have only 1 Read method with the type int, bool, etc.
        return (T) methodInfo?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}

public List<object> ReadAllAsCollection(params Type[] types) 
{
    var result = new List<object>(); // in order to hold various type you need to have a collection of `object` type elements
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Packet).GetMethod("Read");

        MethodInfo genericMethod = method?.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        var res = genericMethod?.Invoke(this, null); // calling Read<T> with appropriate type
        result.Add(res);        
    }

    return result;
}

public T ReadAllAsTuple<T>() where T : ITuple
{
    T CreateValueTuple(List<object> items, Type[] inputTypes)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(ValueTuple)
            .GetMethods()
            .FirstOrDefault(m =>
                m.Name.Contains("Create") &&
                m.GetParameters().Length == items.Count);

        var invokeResult = methodInfo?.MakeGenericMethod(inputTypes)
            .Invoke(null, items.ToArray());

        return (T)invokeResult;
    }

    var tupleType = typeof(T);
    var types = tupleType.GetFields().Select(f => f.FieldType).ToArray();
    
    var result = types
        .Select(t =>
        {
            var method = typeof(Packet).GetMethod("Read");

            var genericMethod = method?.MakeGenericMethod(t);
            return genericMethod?.Invoke(this, null); // calling Read<T> with appropriate type
        }).ToList();

    return result.Any() ?
        CreateValueTuple(result, types)
        : default;
}
```

And a usage:

```cs
var p = new Packet();
var elm = p.Read<int>(); // single instance call, ReadInt() call is encapsulated
var resultAsCollection = p.ReadAllAsCollection(typeof(int), typeof(string));
var resultAsTuple = p.ReadAllAsTuple<ValueTuple<int, string, bool>>();
```

---

A few notes:

1. As you probably want a single exposed `public` method (Read), it would be good to have other methods declared as `private`.
2. In this case, you have simple method names, but to escape possible name conflicts, you can use some specific naming conventions, like: `_ReadInt_()` or any other namings you prefer. Though, this example will work even without specific namings.
3. It is assumed that you will have only one method with the name `Read...` and return type of T (for example `int ReadInt()`) because, for the above case, we are using only the first match.

Comment: I think this changes the syntax from `int myInt = packet.ReadInt()` to `int myInt = packet.Read<int>()` but doesn't address having multiple dynamic parameters in a single function

Comment: @SimoGecko, I've made an update, although it's still worth thinking about how to return results via collection.

Comment: @SimoGecko, after investigating various options, back and forth, I've found another way, which seems a bit more complex but, anyway as a solution. That is done via using tuples. Unfortunately, other solutions seem even more complex for me.