# C# How to pass generic enumerable type parameter to another method expecting an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

I have a method that accepts a basic generic variable in the method signature:

```
public void Foo<T>(T val) {

    if (val is IEnumerable) {
        Bar(val)
    }
}

...Logic if not enumerable
```

The signature for Bar looks like this:

```
private void Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> vals) {
    ...Logic if enumerable
}
```

The logic is very lengthy and different based on whether the item passed in is enumerable or not. I can't get `Bar(val)` to work. I tried the following, let me know what I'm missing:

`Bar(val)`

`Bar((IEnumerable<T>)val)`
(Compiles, but results in this error at run-time when tried with a List of ints:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]]'.'
```

`Bar((IEnumerable)val)`

Comment: You are checking that something is `IEnumerable` and then passing it as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: `if (val is IEnumerable e) { Bar<T>(e); }`, but like I said, that implies  `Bar<T>(IEnumerable vals)`, not `Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> vals)`.

Comment: Simplest way is probably `Bar((dynamic) val)`, although some people will lynch me for even mentioning `dynamic`. The alternative is getting tricksy with `MakeGenericMethod`, which is going to be very involved since you also need to get the generic type `U` of the `IEnumerable<U>` that is `val` (which is not the same as `T`, as you've discovered). Something like `Expression<Action> e = () => Bar<object>(default); ((MethodCallExpression) e.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(val.GetType()).Invoke(this, new object[] { val });`, isn't that fun?

Comment: I am able to retrieve the `T` in the `IEnumerable<T>` if it helps. I should have put this in the main post, but I've tried `Bar((IEnumerable<[valInnerType]>)val)` where `[valInnerType]` is the type being enumerated. Doesn't compile.

Comment: If you have the type at the call site it's easier; `Bar((IEnumerable<innerType>) (object) val)` will compile and do the conversion at runtime.

Comment: I hope the accepted answer will explain why the intuitive `if (val is IEnumerable<T> e) Bar(e)` does not work and why the cast throws an exception.

Comment: @Wyck Why that would not work? I just tried and it worked fine without any problems (indeed class need to implement iterator, but that's quite obvious - `class MyClass : IEnumerable<MyClass> {...}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option without changing the signature and/or using `dynamic` is to dive into reflection. You need to get the closed generic type of `IEnumerable<TInner>` (where `T : IEnumerable<TInner>`), construct corresponding closed version of `Bar` and invoke it. Something along this lines:

```cs
void Foo<T>(T val)
{
    var genericEnumInterface = typeof(T).GetInterfaces()
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
    if (genericEnumInterface is not null)
    {
        MethodInfo mi = ...; // get Bar via reflection
        var constructedMethod = mi.MakeGenericMethod(genericEnumInterface);
        constructedMethod.Invoke(this, new[]{(object)val}); // assuming Bar is in the same class as Foo
    }
}
```

Note that there are types which will implement `IEnumerable<T>` which you possibly will not want to process via `Bar` like `string` which is `IEnumerable<char>`. Another concern is that reflection can cause noticable performance hit in some cases so you can try `caching` it (see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63558546/2501279) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454454/2501279)).

Also personally I would try to avoid such generic method as `Foo` due to possible misuse and corner cases like `string`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go down the reflection route there is another option:

```
if (val is IEnumerable) 
{
    Bar(val as dynamic);
}
```

You may not want to go down that rabbit hole though.