# Why is this generating hash of 0?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use some code that will generate hashcode based on the value of all properties inside an  object, but the following returns a 0 for the `HashCodeOnProperties`

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var request = new Request()
{

    NorthEastLatitude = 43.13306116240615,
    NorthEastLongitude = -80.9355926513672,
    NorthWestLatitude = 43.13306116240615,
    NorthWestLongitude = -81.573486328125014,
    SouthEastLatitude = 42.831667202614092,
    SouthEastLongitude = -80.9355926513672 ,
    SouthWestLatitude = 42.831667202614092,
    SouthWestLongitude = -81.573486328125014
};

var hash = request.GetHashCodeOnProperties();
Console.WriteLine(hash);

Console.ReadKey();


public class Request
{
    public double? SouthWestLatitude { get; set; }
    public double? SouthWestLongitude { get; set; }
    public double? NorthEastLatitude { get; set; }
    public double? NorthEastLongitude { get; set; }


    public double? SouthEastLatitude { get; set; }
    public double? SouthEastLongitude { get; set; }
    public double? NorthWestLatitude { get; set; }
    public double? NorthWestLongitude { get; set; }

}
public static class HashCodeByPropertyExtensions
{
    public static int GetHashCodeOnProperties<T>(this T inspect)
    {
        return inspect.GetType().GetProperties().Select(o => o.GetValue(inspect)).GetListHashCode();
    }

    public static int GetListHashCode<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        return sequence
            .Where(item => item != null)
            .Select(item => item.GetHashCode())
            .Aggregate((total, nextCode) => total ^ nextCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, have you debugged through the code to see what's happening? (Even just adding `.Select(hash => { Console.WriteLine($"Partial hash: {hash}"); return hash; }` would give you more information...)

Comment: But fundamentally, your hash combination code means that if you get the same hash code for two properties, they'll cancel each other out (due to XOR). Now look at the values you've provided in your Request object...

Comment: Consider using [`HashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.hashcode) for scenarios like these; `HashCode.Combine` goes well with `.Aggregate`. You'll also want to take a look at `record`s, as these provide hash code implementations "for free".

Comment: Consider using the [`HashCode` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode) (unless you are on .NET Framework). [Edit: Ah, Jeroen Mostert wrote that while I was typing.] But still interesting to hear the explanation. But as Jon Skeet says, it depends on the value. One thing I see, is the overload of `Aggregate` you use will throw if all the properties have null values. This includes, of course, the case where there are no properties.

Comment: btw, records override `GetHashCode()` and would give you this functionality out of the box: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are xoring values without "offset", so this will result in same values canceling each other out ([exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) is associative and commutative so 42 ^ 77 ^ 42 ^ 77 is equivalent to 42 ^ 42 ^ 77 ^ 77 which is clearly is 0). You can do something like:

```
public static int GetListHashCode<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    var hash = 17;
    return sequence
        .Where(item => item != null)
        .Select(item => item.GetHashCode())
        .Aggregate(hash, (total, nextCode) => unchecked(total*23 + nextCode));
}
```

Or use [`System.HashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode?view=net-7.0) (available since .NET Core 2.1) to perform aggregation:

```
public static int GetListHashCode<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    var hashCode = new HashCode();
    return sequence
        .Where(item => item != null)
        .Select(item => item.GetHashCode())
        .Aggregate(new HashCode(), (code, i) =>
        {
             hashCode.Add(i);
             return hashCode;
        })
        .ToHashCode();
}
```

P.S.

Calculating hashcode should be fast operation, while reflection is usually not very fast approach. Consider using source generators or some dynamic code compilation with expression trees (see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454454/2501279) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63558546/2501279) answers for some inspiration) or switching to using `record`'s which have equality members autogenerated.

Comment: You are not using your `hash = 17` in the first example.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks, was updating the answer, it is fixed now .

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment with images. If your `Request` class is supposed to always represent an *annulus sector* of the Earth whose boundaries follow lines of longitude and latitude, then you need only store coordinates for two diametrically opposite corners.

[image: Polar Earth map with "annulus sector" drawn on top]

[image: Another sector which shares "vertical" borders]

Answer (score 1):

@GuruStron has the correct answer, I just want to include a more robust aggregate hash code function based on code generated by VS.

```
public static int GetListHashCode<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    unchecked
    {
        return sequence.Where(item => item != null)
          .Aggregate(-1817952719, 
            (hc, item) => (-1521134295) * hc + item.GetHashCode()); 
    }
}
```

The values of `-1817952719` and `-1521134295` are just large fancy numbers to replace `17` and  `23` in order to reduce changes for a collision. Also enclosing the operation in `unchecked` is required to avoid any integer overflow exceptions.

--

I got the values from the suggested code when I issue a generate GetHashCode() command in Visual Studio.

[image: fig1]

Comment: Numbers `1817952719` and `1521134295` are not primes in the strict mathematical sense, but since they are relatively prime to `Pow(2, 32)`, they are good enough.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - the negative sign is important. Cast to unsigned int to get  the actual number used internally. They transform to `2477014577` and `2773833001`. But alas, they are not primes either.

Comment: But `-1817952719 + Pow(2, 32)` is also not a mathematical prime (being `16363 * 151379`), so why do people call such numbers "prime"?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - ok I updated my answer not calling them primes anymore. Thank you.