# Conflicting C# generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, decorator

I am implementing a DynamoDBContext decorator that will perform sensitive data tokenization on objects when a value is written or loaded. The class must implement IDynamoDBContext so that it can be injected into its dependents. The implementation uses a third party tokenizer. The tokenization interface has a generic constraint to only tokenize reference "class" types.

The interfaces are both from third party libraries. I cannot change the interface signatures of either.

```cs
interface IDynamoDBContext {
    Task SaveAsync<T>(T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    // ...
}
```

```cs
interface ITokenizer {
    Task<T> TokenizeAsync<T>(T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class;
    // ...
}
```

```cs
class TokenizingDynamoDBContext : IDynamoDBContext {
    private readonly IDynamoDBContext _baseContext;
    private readonly ITokenizer _tokenizer;
    // ...
    public async Task SaveAsync<T>(T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
        if (typeof(T).IsClass)
            value = await _tokenizer.TokenizeAsync(value, cancellationToken);
    
        await _baseContext.SaveAsync(value, cancellationToken);
    }
    // ...
}
```

As presented using the runtime checks to ensure the constraints produces a compiler error:

> CS0452    The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ITokenizer.TokenizeAsync(T)'

I cannot simply cast the TokenizeAsync parameter as `object`. The tokenizer uses type info from the generic type parameter. Casting the value as `object` will result in the value properties not being tokenized correctly.

Attempting to add the `where T : class` constraint to the `TokenizingDynamoDBContext` method causes a compiler error:

> CS0425    The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'TokenizingDynamoDBContext.DeleteAsync(T, CancellationToken)' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'IDynamoDBContext.DeleteAsync(T, CancellationToken)'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.   Dynamo.DataModel

Using explicit interface implementation means that the tokenizing code won't be reached when this is used by its dependents.

I've also tried this:

```cs
class TokenizingDynamoDBContext {
    // ...
    public async Task SaveAsync<T>(T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
        await SaveAsyncImpl(value, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task SaveAsyncImpl<T>(T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : class {
        value = await _tokenizer.TokenizeAsync(value, cancellationToken);
        await _baseContext.SaveAsync(value, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task SaveAsyncImpl<T>(T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : struct {
        await _baseContext.SaveAsync(value, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This produces a compiler error as well with or without the second `where T : struct` constraint:

> CS0111    Type 'TokenizingDynamoDBContext' already defines a member called 'SaveAsyncImpl' with the same parameter types

What is the proper way to make this work?

Comment: the value chain should have the same constraints as the `TokenizeAsync<T>`. You can't pass `T` to another method that has different constraints. So go from the top and check the constraints of `T`, follow it up until you reach `TokenizeAsync<T>` to ensure that `T` has the same constraints all the way.

Comment: @iSR5 Thank you for the comment. The problem is that I have to implement the IDynamoDBContext interface which does not have a constraint on T and call into the ITokenizer interface which does have a constraint on T. I cannot change either interface definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# generic constraints are not a part of method signature so the last try will not work. As for the issue itself - currently compiler does not support something like pattern matching on the generic type parameter, so the only workaround (at least I know of) is to use some reflection.

```
public async Task SaveAsync<T>(T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
    if (typeof(T).IsClass)
    {
        var method = typeof(ITokenizer)
            .GetMethod(nameof(ITokenizer.TokenizeAsync))
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

        value = await (method.Invoke(_tokenizer, new object[] { value, cancellationToken }) as Task<T>);
    }
    
    await _baseContext.SaveAsync(value, cancellationToken);
}
```

If the part of the code is performance critical you can reduce the reflection cost by "caching" it (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63558546/2501279)).

See also:

- [Proposal: Pattern match via generic constraint](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/905)

Comment: don't forget to cache the method info and reuse it.

Comment: @iSR5 Totally agree. That is mentioned in the answer with link to a possible approach to handle that (generic helper class with some reflection + expression trees compilation "magic").