# Static object construction order

Tags: c#, static, c#-12.0

Generally speaking my understanding was that static objects in classes are constructed when the class is referenced for the first time. However I am experiencing a behavior that I did not expected.

Consider the following class

```
public abstract class SmartColor<TColor> where TColor : SmartColor<TColor> {
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, TColor> _items = new();

    protected SmartColor(string code, string name) {
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
        //register all colors
        foreach (var field in typeof(TColor).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)) {
            TColor? item = (TColor?)field.GetValue(null);
            if (item is not null) {
                Register(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public string Code { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public static TColor FromCode(string code) {
        if (_items.TryGetValue(code, out var result)) {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void Register(TColor item) {
        _items.GetOrAdd(item.Code, item);
    }
}
```

which is in turn inherited from this one

```
public class WebColor : SmartColor<WebColor> {
    public static readonly WebColor White = new WebColor("#ffffff", nameof(White));
    public static readonly WebColor Black = new WebColor("#000000", nameof(Black));

    protected WebColor(string code, string name) : base(code, name) {
    }
}
```

It produce a NullReferenceException if used like this

```
public static void Main()
{
    WebColor color = WebColor.FromCode("#ffffff");
    Console.WriteLine(color.Name);
}
```

Can I understand why this is happening? Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FoojY8)

Comment: Even with that in place, a call to `WebColor.FromCode` will be compiled as `Color.FromCode`, so `WebColor` won't be initialized. I would personally avoid trying to be "smart" here.

Comment: Apart from the "smart" name which was just the first name found to create the example code, is there any chance/alternative to see this working by maintaining the code structure?

Comment: Given that `WebColor.FromCode` doesn't in itself initialize `WebColor`, I don't think so. You could add a `FromCode` method to `WebColor` itself, which could just delegate to a method in the base class, perhaps... but this sort of thing feels *really* likely to lead to hard-to-diagnose issues. Do you actually have many "kinds" of color? I'd remove the generics and inheritance and just have `WebColor.FromCode`, `XyzColor.FromCode` etc, all of which use their own separate cache. (That could be a `ColorCache` or something similar to avoid too much duplication, mind you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation for Static Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors):

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to
> perform a particular action that needs to be performed only once. It
> is called automatically before the first instance is created or any
> static members are referenced.

So let's look at this in detail. For your code to work, the static field constructors for class `WebColor` must be called before `WebColor.FromCode("#ffffff")` is called.

Has an instance of `WebColor` been created? No.

Has any of its static members been referenced? No. The `FromCode()` method is *not* a member of `WebColor` - it's a static member of `SmartColor<TColor>`, and although static methods of base classes can be called via a derived class, they are not actually members of that derived class.

Therefore the criteria for calling the static initialisers of `WebColor` have not been fulfilled, so the `White` initialisation has not occured and therefore it has not been added to `_items` in `SmartColor<T>`.

But do note that `_items` itself has been initialised because of the call to `WebColor.FromCode()`.

---

You can fix this in a slightly hacky way by adding a static constructor to `SmartColor<TColor>` as follows:

```
static SmartColor()
{
    Type type = typeof(WebColor);
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(type.TypeHandle);
}
```

The expresses the fact that the static members of `SmartColor<TColor>` have a temporal dependency on the `WebColor` type, and it will force the static `WebColor` initialisers to run when the `SmartColor<TColor>` static initialisers run.

However, as others have pointed out this is a somewhat awkward design, so it might be worth employing a different approach!

---

Addendum:

You can avoid using a static constructor by using a class such as this:

```
public sealed class StaticClassInitialiser<T>
{
    public StaticClassInitialiser()
    {
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(T).TypeHandle);
    }
}
```

And then create a static instance of that class in the `SmartColor<TColor>` class:

```
static readonly StaticClassInitialiser<WebColor> _ = new();
```

That might fool SonarQube, but it's hardly an improvement - I include it here only for curiosity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am going to accept this as the most complete, even if also others have pointed out similar solutions and described the problems of this design. Also, static constructor are not recommended by static code analysis tools. Example [Sonarsource](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-3963/)

Answer (score 2):

If you'll check the decompilation (for example @[sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)) you will see that `WebColor.FromCode("#ffffff");` call is actually:

```
IL_000b: ldstr "#ffffff"
IL_0010: call !0 class SmartColor`1<class WebColor>::FromCode(string)
IL_0015: stloc.0
```

i.e. it is call to `SmartColor<WebColor>.FromCode` which does not require initialization for `WebColor`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors):

> It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced. A static constructor will be called at most once.

`FromCode` does not create any instances of `WebColor` or uses any static props from it.

One way to fix this is to move the initialization logic to the static ctor of `SmartColor` (make `Register` method static also or just inline it):

```
static SmartColor()
{
    foreach (var field in typeof(TColor).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)) {
        TColor? item = (TColor?)field.GetValue(null);
        if (item is not null) {
            Register(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Using static generic types with some init logic in ctors was a trick I used a lot when I needed to ["cache" reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63558546/2501279) before source generators became available, but usually I had done this via a separate type without extra inheritance.

Comment: Thanks very much for the sharplab suggestion. I was'nt aware of it.