# How to check for nullable while using a property selector

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable, nullable-reference-types

Given the following class

```
   public class Anonymizer : IAnonymizer
{
    public void Anonymize<TEntity, TProperty>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        var value = typeof(TProperty) switch
        {
            { } t when IsNullable(t)  => (TProperty?)(object) null!,
            { } t when t == typeof(string) => (TProperty) (object) "<Anonymized>",
            { } t when t == typeof(int) => (TProperty) (object) -1,
            _ => default,
        };
        
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body;
        var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
        property.SetValue(entity, value);
    }

    private static bool IsNullable(Type t)
    {
        return !t.IsValueType ||  Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null;
    }
}
```

and the following tests

```
  [Fact]
    public void Test_string()
    {
        var sut = new Anonymizer();
        
        var myObject = new MyClass {MyText = "Hello World", MyNumber = 42};

        sut.Anonymize(myObject, e => e.MyText);

        myObject.MyText.Should().Be("<Anonymized>");
        myObject.MyNumber.Should().Be(42);
    }

    
    [Fact]
    public void Test_int()
    {
        var sut = new Anonymizer();
        
        var myObject = new MyClass {MyText = "Hello World", MyNumber = 42};

        sut.Anonymize(myObject, e => e.MyNumber);

        myObject.MyText.Should().Be("Hello World");
        myObject.MyNumber.Should().Be(-1);
    }
    
        
    [Fact]
    public void Test_NullableString()
    {
        var sut = new Anonymizer();
        
        var myObject = new MyClass
        {
            MyText = "Hello World", 
            MyNumber = 42,
            MyNullableString = "Hello World"
        };

        sut.Anonymize(myObject, e => e.MyNullableString);
        
        myObject.MyNumber.Should().Be(42);
        myObject.MyNullableString.Should().BeNull();
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public string MyText { get; set; }
        public int MyNumber { get; set; }
        public string? MyNullableString { get; set; }
    }
```

It seems like there is no way to distinguish between a property of type "string" and "string?". It seems like TProperty will be "string" in both cases.

Any suggestions

Comment: Vote to reopen (not duplicate): It is not because two questions have a similar answer that they started from the same problem. At time of asking it was still open to be potentially improved in the expression signature or type parameters. The problem at hand are not similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to analyze the [`NullabilityInfoContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.nullabilityinfocontext?view=net-8.0), something along these lines:

```
public class Anonymizer : IAnonymizer
{
    public void Anonymize<TEntity, TProperty>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        var value = typeof(TProperty) switch
        {
            { } t when IsNullableValueType(t)  => (TProperty?)(object) null!,
            { } t when IsNullableReferenceType(propertySelector)  => (TProperty?)(object) null!,
            // ...
        };
        
        // ...
    }

    private static bool IsNullableValueType(Type t) => Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null;
    
    private static bool IsNullableReferenceType<TEntity, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        if (typeof(TProperty).IsValueType) return false;
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body;
        var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;

        NullabilityInfoContext context = new();
        var nullabilityInfo = context.Create(property); 
        return nullabilityInfo.ReadState == NullabilityState.Nullable;
    }
}
```

Note that invoking reflection in this manner every time can be costly (or even not available in some cases), so you should consider following options:

- Using [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) (without better overview of codebase and use cases it is hard to tell if it is feasible)
- Cache reflection (see one of the following answers: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63558546/2501279), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454454/2501279), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62032288/2501279) to get some ideas)